# jOOQ TransactionListener never gets called

Tags: jooq, spring-transactions

I am trying to attach a transaction listener to my jOOQ DSL configuration but none of its method gets ever called.

**DSL context configuration**

```java
@Bean
public Configuration dslConfiguration(DataSourceConnectionProvider connectionProvider) {
    return new DefaultConfiguration()
            .set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
            .set(connectionProvider)
            .set(new DefaultTransactionProvider(connectionProvider)) // <-- probably unnecessary
            .set(new TxListener()) // <-- here
            .set(executeListener());
}
```

**Transaction manager**

```java
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

(Just checked that my calls are done within a transaction: updated some data, threw an exception, data remains unchanged.)

[image]